# SMS Email Does not work with VB6/CDO

Tags: .net, email, vb6, smtp

In the past I have sent an SMS message to my Sprint phone via the email "9990001111@messaging.sprintpcs.com" and it has worked flawlessly. Now I think the IT department has changed something because it just will not go through. I say this because in .NET it works with no issues:

```
    Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("mail.mycompany.com")

    Dim fromAddress As String = "Me.Developer@mycompany.com"
    Dim toAdddress As String = "9990001111@messaging.sprintpcs.com"

    'subject and body text depend on text message type
    Dim subj As String = "", body As String = ""
    subj = "Warning: Low trip count on 2014-02-06"
    body = "Trip count <= 200. Please review log file."

    With mailClient
        Debug.Print("Host=" & .Host)
        Debug.Print("Port=" & .Port)
        Debug.Print("DeliveryMethod=" & .DeliveryMethod.ToString)
        Debug.Print("EnableSsl=" & .EnableSsl.ToString)
        Debug.Print("UseDefaultCredentials=" & .UseDefaultCredentials)
    End With

    'send the email
    mailClient.Send(fromAddress, toAdddress, subj, body)
```

In my corporate Outlook client I can manually create an email and send it to the same email address and it will arrive no problem.

Now in VB6 using CDO I tried to use all the same properties but it just doesn't arrive. Ive even added a CC to a gmail address and it arrives there but not to the phone. here is what the VB6/CDO code looks like:

```
'use CDO to setup an email object
Dim cdoConfig As CDO.Configuration
Dim cdoMessage As CDO.Message
Dim cdofields As Object

'Create new configuration object
Set cdoConfig = New CDO.Configuration
Set cdofields = cdoConfig.Fields
Set cdoMessage = New CDO.Message

With cdofields
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "mail.mycompany.com"
    .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

    .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoAnonymous
    .Item(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = False                 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
    .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 60

    'if mail server requires outgoing authentication uncomment the lines below and use a valid email address and password.
    '.Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic 'basic (clear-text) authentication
    '.Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoNTLM
    '.Item(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    '.Item(cdoSendUserName) = "Joe Dirt"
    '.Item(cdoSendPassword) = "doughnuts"

    .Update
End With
DoEvents

'set message configuration
Set cdoMessage.Configuration = cdoConfig

'set message contents
With cdoMessage
    .Sender = "Me.Developer@mycompany.com"
    .From = "Me Developer"
    .Subject = "Warning: Low trip count on 2014-02-06"
    .TextBody = "Trip count <= 200. Please review log file."
    .To = "9990001111@messaging.sprintpcs.com"
    .CC = "me.developer@gmail.com"
End With

'send message
cdoMessage.Send
```

Just cant figure out why it works with .NET and native Outlook but not with VB6/CDO.

Comment: So you're saying that the .NET code does not use ssl or authentication?

Comment: Are you using a valid email address for your `fromAddress`?

Comment: The .NET code doesn't use any authentication. The debug shows Host=mail.mycompany.com, Port=25, DeliveryMethod=Network, EnableSsl=False, UseDefaultCredentials=False. I use the same valid From email address for both .NET and VB6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using CDO to relay the message through mail.mycompany.com.  The mail server logs for mail.mycompany.com should show a) whether or not mail.mycompany.com received the message from your application, and if so, b) whether or not delivery to 9990001111@messaging.sprintpcs.com was successful.  If, not the logs should show the reason for the failure.  From the mail server logs, you should be able to isolate the problem.

Comment: yes I use that mail server for both the .NET and the VB6/DCO implementation. but I am not in the IT department and getting to the mail server logs would be an effort in and of itself.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  It's tough to troubleshoot mail delivery problems without access to the logs...

Comment: my confusion is that it works with .NEt with the default settings but in VB6 it just doesnt work.

Comment: There must be some difference between the two.  That's why you need the logs.  The logs will show you why one is failing and one is working.

Comment: Instead of using your company's mail server, maybe you can use a different mail server, that gives you access to the logs (such as http://www.ultrasmtp.com).

Comment: I don't have any budget in my group to pay for the mail server but it may be worth it for the trial. I'm just confused as to why one works and the other doesn't. I may just write a COM Callable Wrapper and see how that pans out.